# Cannot set up a SubscriptionFilter with cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an issue regarding setting up a subscription filter with cloudformation. This is how my CF file looks like

```
  FeedbackSubscriptionFilter:
    Type: AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter
    Properties:
      RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/CloudwatchKinesis'
      LogGroupName: '/aws/lambda/function'
      FilterPattern: ''
      DestinationArn: 'arn:aws:firehose:eu-west-1:yyyyyyyyyy:deliverystream/function-delivery'
```

When I go into the stack panel and update my current stack with this new CF file; I get the following error:

```
The following resource(s) failed to create: [FeedbackSubscriptionFilter].

Could not deliver test message to specified Firehose stream. Check if the given Firehose stream is in ACTIVE state. (Service: AWSLogs; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 76wg79567w048h70w96hwj)
```

However, my stream does seem to work otherwise, I can use the built in send test data just fine.

What am I doing wrong here? I believe it does find the stream, it just cannot send any data to it.

Comment: Are you deploying this CloudFormation stack in `eu-west-1`?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I have exactly the same problem :(

Comment: Did anyone solve this??